# Where are systemd's configurations for cgroups?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

My understanding is that, by default, systemd will start all processes under a single cgroup where cpu.share=1024. If you choose to override the cpu.share for a service, it will create a new cgroup for the processes under that service with cpu.share set to whatever value you've chosen.

I want to manually create a new cgroup with a custom cpu.share that gives me 60% of the CPU. To do that, I need to know the cpu.share values for all existing cgroups. Where is systemd setting these values? Is there an easy way for me to get this? /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu only contains the root group (set to 1024) and the groups I've manually created.

Answer (score 1):

systemd's CGroup options are documented in [`man systemd.exec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) (or in [`man systemd.resource-control`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#CPUWeight=weight)). It sounds like the one you are looking for is:

> `CPUWeight=weight`,
>   `StartupCPUWeight=weight`
>
> Assign the specified CPU time weight to the processes executed, if the
>   unified control group hierarchy is used on the system. These options
>   take an integer value and control the "`cpu.weight`" control group
>   attribute. The allowed range is 1 to 10000. Defaults to 100. For
>   details about this control group attribute, see [cgroup-v2.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) and
>   [sched-design-CFS.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-design-CFS.txt). The available CPU time is split up among
>   all units within one slice relative to their CPU time weight.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that, by default, systemd will start all processes under a single cgroup where cpu.share=1024.

I do not believe this is correct.  However, please don't take my word as authoritative.  Here are the portions of the docs that lead me to this conclusion:

From `systemd.resource-control(5)`:

> ```
>    CPUAccounting=
>        Turn on CPU usage accounting for this unit. Takes a boolean argument.
>        Note that turning on CPU accounting for one unit might also implicitly
>        turn it on for all units contained in the same slice and for all its
>        parent slices and the units contained therein. The system default for
>        this setting maybe controlled with DefaultCPUAccounting= in systemd-
>        system.conf(5).
> ```

And also:

> ```
>    CPUShares=weight, StartupCPUShares=weight
>        ...
>       Those options imply "CPUAccounting=true".
> ```

As I read it, if no units have a value set for `CPUShares` and `CPUAccounting` is not explicitly enabled anywhere (and `DefaultCPUAccounting` is not set in `system.conf`) then systemd may not (will not?) use the `cpu` hierarchy at all.

(I would welcome any correction on this point.)