# daemon reload resets cgroup.subtree_control of cgroups

Tags: linux, systemd, linux-kernel, daemon, cgroups

I created a cgroup named `mycgroup` using `mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup`.

Before executing `echo +cpu > /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup/cpu.max
cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup/cpu.max: No such file or directory
```

After executing `echo +cpu > /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control`:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup/cpu.max
max 100000
```

But after executing `systemctl daemon-reload`:

```
[root@host ~]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup/cpu.max
cat: /sys/fs/cgroup/mycgroup/cpu.max: No such file or directory
```

Daemon reload is resetting the `cgroup.subtree_control` file. How do I make the setting permanent so that daemon reload does not remove cpu from the file?

Comment: The subtree_control modifications don't survive reboot either. I would very much like to discover how the defaults are set also. I have other Debian installs that default to having the cpu controller enabled in subtree_control.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Quote from [Where are systemd's configurations for cgroups?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/428317/where-are-systemds-configurations-for-cgroups/466164#466164)

> As I read it, if no units have a value set for CPUShares and CPUAccounting is not explicitly enabled anywhere (and DefaultCPUAccounting is not set in system.conf) then systemd may not (will not?) use the cpu hierarchy at all.

This is mostly true. Simply putting the line `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` into `/etc/systemd/system.conf` had no effect for me.

The takeaway: **If no service unit files require the CPU controller, it seems systemd doesn't turn it on.**

So I tested it. I rebooted into a fresh Debian 12 system.

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
memory pids
```

I added this to the `[Service]` section of `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service`:

```
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495013/237874
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494843/how-to-limit-a-systemd-service-to-play-nice-with-the-cpu/495013#495013
CPUQuota=75%
```

Then...

```
systemctl daemon-reload
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
cpu memory pids
```

Even after a reboot, subtree_control still lists cpu!

Edit: `CPUQuota=75%` in the `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` file produces this:

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/system.slice/nginx.service/cpu.max
75000 100000
```